# Conectar socket externo a contenedor de Docker

Tags: nodejs, docker, socket, docker-compose, telegram

Estoy trabajando con Docker y me encuentro con lo que parece ser un problema de red.
Para darle contexto he desarrollado un backend con NodeJS que básicamente utiliza la librería Gram.js que provee una interfaz para trabajar con la API de Telegram.
En local todo funciona perfectamente y puedo establecer conexión con los servidores de telegram. El método que hace esto es `TelegramClient()`.

Al pasar la app a un contenedor con node:20.9.0-alpine3.18, la aplicación se monta y el servidor responde, pero al utilizar `new TelegramClient()` este no puede completar su desenlace.
Estuve investigando y parece que TelegramClient se comunica mediante socket, y ahí pareciera estar el problema con el contenedor.
Destaco que he mapeado los puertos del mismo de la siguiente manera: 8000:8000.

En la documentación oficial de gram.js provee una forma de especificar un proxy, pero no termino de entender cómo funciona ni si aplicaría para este caso.

Comparto los logs del despliegue en local (funcionando correctamente) y luego los logs en el contenedor.
En local (Correcto):

```
[2023-11-21T18:50:09.003] [INFO] - [Running gramJS version 2.19.9]
[2023-11-21T18:50:09.006] [INFO] - [Connecting to 149.154.167.91:80/TCPFull...]
[2023-11-21T18:50:09.007] [DEBUG] - [Connecting]
[2023-11-21T18:50:09.264] [DEBUG] - [Finished connecting]
[2023-11-21T18:50:09.265] [DEBUG] - [Connection success!]
[2023-11-21T18:50:09.267] [DEBUG] - [New auth_key attempt ...]
[2023-11-21T18:50:09.528] [DEBUG] - [Starting authKey generation step 1]
[2023-11-21T18:50:09.529] [DEBUG] - [Finished authKey generation step 1]
[2023-11-21T18:50:09.787] [DEBUG] - [Step 2 : Generated a secure aes encrypted data]
[2023-11-21T18:50:10.575] [DEBUG] - [Finished authKey generation step 2]
[2023-11-21T18:50:10.576] [DEBUG] - [Starting authKey generation step 3]
[2023-11-21T18:50:11.159] [DEBUG] - [Finished authKey generation step 3]
[2023-11-21T18:50:11.160] [DEBUG] - [Generated new auth_key successfully]
[2023-11-21T18:50:11.161] [DEBUG] - [Starting send loop]
[2023-11-21T18:50:11.162] [DEBUG] - [Waiting for messages to send... false]
[2023-11-21T18:50:11.163] [DEBUG] - [Starting receive loop]
[2023-11-21T18:50:11.164] [DEBUG] - [Receiving items from the network...]
[2023-11-21T18:50:11.165] [INFO] - [Connection to 149.154.167.91:80/TCPFull complete!]
[2023-11-21T18:50:11.166] [INFO] - [Using LAYER 166 for initial connect]
(Continúa...)
```

En el contenedor:

```
[2023-11-21T21:44:23.371] [INFO] - [Running gramJS version 2.19.9]
[2023-11-21T21:44:23.375] [INFO] - [Connecting to 149.154.167.91:80/TCPFull...]
[2023-11-21T21:44:23.375] [DEBUG] - [Connecting]
[2023-11-21T21:44:23.378] [DEBUG] - [Finished connecting]
[2023-11-21T21:44:23.379] [DEBUG] - [Connection success!]
[2023-11-21T21:44:23.380] [DEBUG] - [New auth_key attempt ...]
(No avanza más)
```

He revisado las variables de entorno y no parece haber problemas allí...

---

Estuve investigando un poco más y encontré esto en la documentación de telegram

> TCP
> The TCP transport is implemented simply by sending the payloads generated by the chosen MTProto transport over a plain TCP socket on ports 80, 443, 5222 or other (a different port number may be returned by help.getConfig).
> Note that if the this_port_only dcOption flag is set, clients must use only the specified port, without trying any other port.
> Also note that if the force_try_ipv6 config flag is set, clients must prioritize IPv6 over IPv4 for all MTProto transports, even if an IPv4 connection is available.
>
> Framing is managed by the chosen MTProto transport protocol.
>
> There are no implicit acknowledgments for the TCP transport: all messages must be acknowledged explicitly. Most frequently, acknowledgments are placed in a container with the next query or response if it is transmitted in short order. For example, this is almost always the case for client messages containing RPC queries: the acknowledgment normally arrives with the RPC response.

He probado habilitando los puertos 80, 443 y 5222 del contenedor, pero no percibido cambios.